# Implement `IntegerMath addition` and `IntegerMath subtraction` without using lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, interface

I'm currently learning the concept of Lambda in java and I have encountered the following code. The `IntegerMath addition` and `IntegerMath subtraction` were defined using lambda. However, I was just curious how to implement `IntegerMath addition` and `IntegerMath subtraction`  without using lambda? It would be great if the suggestion can be accompanied by some code! Thanks in advance for any help!

```
public class Calculator {

    interface IntegerMath {
        int operation(int a, int b);   
    }

    public int operateBinary(int a, int b, IntegerMath op) {
        return op.operation(a, b);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Calculator myApp = new Calculator();
        IntegerMath addition = (a, b) -> a + b;
        IntegerMath subtraction = (a, b) -> a - b;
        System.out.println("40 + 2 = " +
            myApp.operateBinary(40, 2, addition));
        System.out.println("20 - 10 = " +
            myApp.operateBinary(20, 10, subtraction));    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambdas are *functionally* equivalent to [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) like,

```
IntegerMath addition = new IntegerMath() {
    @Override
    public int operation(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};
IntegerMath subtraction = new IntegerMath() {
    @Override
    public int operation(int a, int b) {
        return a - b;
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you! i'm seen this kind of syntax pattern for the first time so was struggling a little bit.